# Difference between csv.reader and .read when importing csv file

Tags: python

What is the difference in importing csv file with reader and with .read

```
import csv
f = open("nfl.csv", 'r')
data = csv.reader(f)
```

and using read directly

```
f = open('nfl.csv', 'r')
data = f.read()
```

Comment: `f.read()` just reads a file and has no concept of CSV. `data = csv.reader(f)` assigns the reader object to the name `data`, but does not consume it, compared to for example `data = list(csv.reader(f))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), the `reader` will

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   csvfile.

whereas the `read` on a file, will

> reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. size is an optional
>   numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire
>   contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if
>   the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory.

So, the first way, you can use

```
for row in reader:
```

and processes the lines one at a time.
You can also do things one line at a time for a file in general.

The csv module expects comma seprated columns though, so you get a list or a dictionary of the data depending on how you set things up.

Comment: thank you ! Atleast I know I must look in the documents first :)